# Did a sourcebook or other reference source ever contain an error about the uses/day of the Immediate Magic ACF?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, alternate-class-feature

[Once upon a time](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?322536-The-Crowd-Calls-for-Blood!-D-amp-D-3-5-lvl-6-PvP-arena/page11), I made a rules error:  I believed that the Immediate Magic alternate Wizard class feature (PHB2 p. 68) was usable (3+int bonus) times/day.  I was so certain of this that I didn't even bother looking up the rule; I just *knew* it was (3+int bonus)/day.  However, reading the source book itself, the rule is actually:

> ...you can use this spell-like ability a number of times per day equal to your Intelligence bonus (minimum 1).

When I reported this error to my DM at the time, he replied that he had *also* thought it was (3+int bonus)/day, and was surprised to find we were both wrong.

---

Today, reading over old questions, I noticed [two](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19557/what-wizard-schools-are-best-to-specialize-in-which-schools-are-best-to-sacrifi/19558#19558) [answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50893/what-can-a-wizard-take-instead-of-a-familiar-at-1st-level/50898#50898) in which local 3.5 guru KRyan *also* thought Immediate Magic was usable (3+int bonus)/day.  Both of these answers were posted before I knew StackExchange was a thing; I am unlikely to have inherited the error from reading KRyan's posts.

Once is happenstance.  Twice is coincidence.  Three times is enemy action.  Where did we all pick up this misconception?

Did a previous printing of the PHB2 state a different number of uses/day for this ability?  Or did some famous source (a well-known guide that we all would have read, for instance) make this error, and we all inherited it from there?

Comment: Whoa. I am right there with you, I was just *sure* it was (3+Int)/day. But my *PHB2* (a first printing I think) also says Int/day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Immediate magic's always been usable a number of times per day equal to the possessor's Intelligence modifier

So far as I'm aware, the May 2006 printing is the sole printing of the *Player's Handbook II*. (Both the book's [*Amazon* entry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786939184) and its [*Wikipedia* entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Player%27s_Handbook_II) agree on this; also, my own print version is a first (only) edition, too.) [The Wizards of the Coast Web site mentions immediate magic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22immediate%20magic%22%20site%3Awizards.com&rlz=1C1AOHY_enUS709US709&oq=%22immediate%20magic%22%20site%3Awizards.com&aqs=chrome..69i57.10351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in but one article—the Eberron Expanded column titled, appropriately enough, ["*Payer's Handbook II*"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebee/20060911a). The Excerpts column ["*Player's Handbook II*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060501a) Excerpt" omits immediate magic. None of the three [*Player's Handbook II* Web enhancements](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/we&page=2) deal with immediate magic.  Were you led astray by an *official* source, I don't know what it is.

I think it's probably the special ability immediate magic's similarity to the cleric's special ability [turn or rebuke undead](http://dndsrd.net/cleric.html#cleric-turn-or-rebuke-undead)—that's usable 3/day plus a number of times per day equal to the cleric's Charisma modifier—that might've led to the confusion, but there's no way to be sure.